# JavaScript - why does inclusion of parenthesis result in an error in ternary expression?

Tags: javascript, operator-precedence, conditional-operator

I have the following code:

```js
const showMessage = msg => console.log(msg);

let person = {
  firstName: `Mick`,
  lastName: `McCarthy`,
  firstTimeUser: true
}

(person.firstTimeUser === true) ? showMessage(`Welcome, ${person.firstName}!`): showMessage(`Glad you're back, ${person.firstName}!`)
```

This results in the error:

```
home.js:7 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'person' before initialization
    at home.js:7
```

However, in the following case (where the parentheses in the ternary expression have been removed):

```js
const showMessage = msg => console.log(msg);

let person = {
  firstName: `Mick`,
  lastName: `McCarthy`,
  firstTimeUser: true
}

person.firstTimeUser === true ? showMessage(`Welcome, ${person.firstName}!`) : showMessage(`Glad you're back, ${person.firstName}!`)
```

There is no error and the welcome message displays correctly.

Why should this be the case? I was under the impression that parentheses were optional in the ternary expression. I imagine that it is *something* to do with order of evaluation, but since the ternary expression is on a different line to `let person = {...`, I am unclear as to why this is happening.

In fact, in the example shown by the JavaScript course I am taking, the instructor shows the following example working perfectly with or without parenthesis:

```
let price = 20

(price < 10) ? showMessage('yes') : showMessage('no')
```

However when I try it on my own machine, the same problem occurs. Could they be using an older version of JavaScript in which the behaviour is different? If so, what has changed?

Many thanks!

Comment: probably you need a semicolon.

Comment: Automatic semicolon insertion doesn't kick in before an opening parenthesis, so it treats it as if you're trying to call a function on `person`. `20` couldn't be anything callable, so there's no ambiguity.

Comment: @LouisCowell Semicolons are not optional. They are not mandatory either. They are complicated. How automatic semicolon works is that javascript will attempt to attach the next line of code into the current line and try to compile it. If it results in an invalid syntax then it tries adding a semicolon between the lines. It used to be that everyone will tell you to use semicolon because there is no way a human can think like that efficiently. But a bunch of people decided to try to find all cases where semicolons are needed - that became the standardjs standard..

Comment: .. if you don't want to use semicolons you **must** follow the standardjs style guide. If not you **must** use semicolons. Standardjs - https://standardjs.com/

Comment: @slebetman Fascinating, thank you. I'll look into it. You're right, I was assuming (actually I think I was told) that semicolons were optional in JavaScript. I see now that I was wrong about this. Thanks again for the insight.

Comment: Semicolons are necessary, full stop. ASI is a crutch to try to make the language more "forgiving" for beginners, but leads to a bunch of problems. I sympathise with forgetting semicolons - we all do it - but I cannot comprehend the argument that they are "optional" and can, or even should, be omitted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript's semi-colon insertion

Here's how the JavaScript engine sees your code

```
let person = {...}(person.firstTime === true ? )
```

The same problem will occur for the following as well

```
console.log('Error')

[1, 2, 3].forEach(console.log)
```

But If there was a semi colon at the end of console.log('Error') then the following code will work normally

Essential, do not depend on JavaScript semi-colon insertion or you will get weird bugs.

Comment: what's the relation between `console.log('Error')`?

Comment: You didn't answer why the last snippet worked with OP's instructor's machine (as claimed)

Comment: @yqlim In my naïveté, I had assumed that semicolons are optional, so excluded them from the instructor's code for consistency with my own. However, it turns out they are not (see above!).

Comment: @LouisCowell use an automatic linter in your editor and say goodbye to these silly problems. VSCode and ESlint